# Which is the best approach of calling Store Procedures in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have genereated a EF Model from a MS SQL database and I have included both StoredProcedures and Tables. I want to implement stored procedures in my project. Which is the best approach that has more advantages?

```
var data = db.DARs.SqlQuery("db.sp_GetEmployees").ToList();
```

or

```
var data2 = db.sp_GetEmployees().ToList();
```

Here is full code:

```
private UniversityEntities1 db = new UniversityEntities1(); 

public List<DAR> test()
{    
    var data = db.DARs.SqlQuery("db.sp_GetEmployees").ToList();
    var data2 = db.sp_GetEmployees.ToList();
    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's better to use mapper stored procedutes instead of calling plain SQL text (in your exmple `data2`).

It's better becouse EF generates result row with particular datatypes that your stored procedure returns. And you don't need to map it in your code - EF do it for you. Then you can work with result like you work with collection that contains objects with typed fields.

Answer (score 1):

I would also like to add that by using

```
var data2 = db.sp_GetEmployees().ToList();
```

you make sure that renaming the procedure results in a compile error every time you are using that statement. These can be fixed quickly.

If you are just using a string you will have to remember to replace all occurences of the procedure name in the whole project. The project itself will compile.

Comment: It won't result in compile error. You will get an error only when this code will be executed